# Invalid character constant occurs in ADT Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to decrypt an encrypted text in an android program,

```
Public Decrypt{
byte[] arrayOfByte1 = new byte[1024];
arrayOfByte1[0] = 67;
arrayOfByte1[1] = -59;
arrayOfByte1[2] = 84;
arrayOfByte1[3] = 43;
arrayOfByte1[4] = 99;
...
arrayOfByte1['Â€'] = 12;
}
```

When I try to define 'Â€' char's value "Invalid character constant" error occurs.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Â€` is 2 characters and that's why you get an error about an invalid character constant.

You have to use a single character:

```
arrayOfByte1['Â'] = 12;
arrayOfByte1['€'] = 13;
```